# Removing special characters from a list of strings Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of strings

```
["This!","i2s","a","li!st","of","strings"]
```

And I want to make a function such that it removes all the special characters from individual strings

```
["This", "is", "a", "list", "of", "strings"]
```

I made a function like this(I'm only considering ! as special characters for now):

```
removeUglyCharacters []=[]
removeUglyCharacters (x:xs) | x == "!"  = removeUglyCharacters xs
                            | otherwise = x:removeUglyCharacters xs
```

However, if I understand correctly, this will check if one string is an exclamation and then continue.

```
*Main> let abc = ["this","wont","work","as!","intended","!"]
*Main> removeUglyCharacters abc
["this","wont","work","as!","intended"]
```

It will not check every character in a string and remove the exclamation. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. I was thinking along the lines of needing a pattern match for every individual string too?

Answer (score 1):

You should first make a function to remove `'!'` from a *single* string. The only thing that you have to change for that is replacing `"!"` with `'!'`:

```
removeUglyCharacters :: String -> String
removeUglyCharacters [] = []
removeUglyCharacters (x:xs) | x == '!'  = removeUglyCharacters xs
                            | otherwise = x:removeUglyCharacters xs
```

Then you can make a `map`ping where you map each string with the `removeUglyCharacters`:

```
removeFromListOfStrings :: [String] -> [String]
removeFromListOfStrings = map removeUglyCharacters
```

Your `removeUglyCharacters` can be replaced with a `filter ('!' /=)`, so that means that we can work with:

```
removeFromListOfStrings :: [String] -> [String]
removeFromListOfStrings = map (filter ('!' /=))
```

You can limit the filtering further to only allow characters in the A-Z a-z range. For example with:

```
import Data.Char(isAsciiLower, isAsciiUpper)

removeFromListOfStrings :: [String] -> [String]
removeFromListOfStrings = map (filter (\c -> isAsciiLower c || isAsciiUpper c))
```